# is ker(T) = N([T]b) if B is the base of the representative matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've been given the following question:

> T is a linear transformation T:R2[x]->R2[x]. You are given [T]b and b
>   itself. Find ker(T).
>
> Is N([T]b) = ker(T)?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my lacking English, I'm not a native English speaker and am really unfamiliar with the mathematical terms in English.

Answer (score 0):

The set $\ker (\textsf T)$ consist of all those polynomials $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 \in \Bbb{R}_2[x]$ such that $\textsf{T}(p(x))=0$. And the set $\textsf{N}([\textsf T]_b)$ consist of all those $3$-tuples $(a_0,a_1,a_2)^t \in \Bbb{R}^3$ such that
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_0\\a_1\\a_2 \end{pmatrix} [\textsf T]_b = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$
In principle, the sets are not the same, but they do relate in a certain way :
$$\phi_b (\ker(\textsf T)) = \textsf{N}([\textsf T]_b)$$
(where $\phi_b : \Bbb{R}_2[x] \to \Bbb{R}^3$ is the standard representation of $\Bbb{R}_2[x]$ with respect to the basis $b$).